# Symony get data from ajax function to Symfony controller and flush

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, parameters, request

I'd like to retrieve data from an ajax action and pass it to my Symfony Controller in order to execute a flush() action on it.

My ajax looks like that (documentlist is a multiselect dropdown):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#{{ form.vars.name }}_documentlist').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{ path('documentBundle_document_bulkDeactivate') }}",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("form").serialize(),
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

and within my controller I'd like to do the following:

```
    /**
  * @Route("/document/bulkdeactivate", name="documentBundle_document_bulkDeactivate")
  * @Template()
  */
  public function bulkDeactivateAction(Request $request) {

      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $form = $this->createForm(DocumentDeactivationType::class);
      $form->handleRequest($request);
      $selected_documents = $request->request->get('documentlist');
      dump($selected_documents);
      if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
        foreach($selected_documents as $document) {
             $document->setActive(false);
             $em->persist($document);
             $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'The document has been deactivated!'
            );
            return $this->redirectToRoute('documentBundle_document_list');
            }
          }
          return $this->render('DocumentBundle:Panels:ActivationPanel.html.twig', array(
           'form' => $form->createView(),
          ));
    }
```

so since it is possible to select several documents in my **documentlist** I thought, I'd get the **request** data from the ajax and then with a foreach loop, iterate over every single document and **deactivate** it. 
I'm very unexperienced with javascript so I bet there must be something wrong with my ajax function but as well with my controller because if I dump the **selected documents** it always returns null.
When selecting elements from the dropdown, the ajax is actually doing something and I get values for the POST parameters, so this works, but that's about it what I can tell you.

Comment: try moving the line with the $selected_documents above the ->handleRequest, then dumping it. something is tickling my memory that if you handle the request it clears all of the fields in the request

Comment: @MEmerson unfortunately it didn't help. $selected_documents is still null. In my ajax I get the exception "Call to a member function setActive() on null" even though the "handleRequest" is now the last thing I do before my if statement. Any ideas?

Comment: In your HTML assign an id to your form (ie. id="myForm"). Then change this  line  $("form").serialize() to be $("#myForm").serialize. Also if you use chrome verify that the serialization is happening like you expect by opening the dev tools (CTRL SHIFT I) before you click what ever submits, navigate to the network tab, then when you click you should see the AJAX request go out. Click on the page name, and then click on the Headers tab and look for your serialized data in there, those are the headers your browser is sending to PHP, maybe you're not actually sending any data.